# Call NSTextview complete: in menu?

Tags: cocoa, xcode4

I want to add a Complete menu item like TextEdit in Edit menu, but First Responder has no complete: action. How do I link it?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: The `complete:` method is provided by `NSTextView` and `NSResponder`, it *should appear* as an action for `First Responder`. Provide more details as to what you're doing and maybe someone can figure out why you are not seeing it.

Comment: I am new to Cocoa and Objective C, I am using OS X 10.8 and Xcode 4.6.2, I build a single window interface and have a NSTextView inside. After adding a complete menu item, I try to ctrl-drag it to First Responder on left screen, but pop up no complete: found.

Comment: strange, it is indeed missing... How to get it back in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I've no idea why the `complete:` action is not listed - I just tested in a new project and it is indeed missing. However here is how to make it show up:

1. In IB select the "First Responder"
2. Go to the Attributes Inspector (View > Utilities > Show Attributes Inspector
3. If the First Responder section is not expanded click on the disclosure triangle
4. You should see a table labelled "User Defined" with columns "Action" and "Type"
5. Click + at bottom to add a new row
6. Double-click the "action" entry that has appeared to edit it, enter "complete", hit return.

After that when you drag to the First Responder `complete:` should be there.

HTH

Comment: If that’s the case, it’s probably worth filing a radar requesting `-complete:` on First Responder.

Comment: this is amazing, even I din't bother to search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own action..

And then link that method to the `menu`.

For its working, you need to write your own logic, algorithm etc. This doesn't come with any pre-defined method as with Cut, Copy, Print.

Then you need to implement this delegate :

```
- (NSArray *)control:(NSControl *)control
            textView:(NSTextView *)textView
         completions:(NSArray *)words
 forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange
 indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)index;
```

Comment: You shouldn’t give it any name since `NSTextView` responds to `-complete:` and shows a completion list upon receiving that (predefined) message.